# Android: Controlling of DB Versions

Tags: android, database, sqlite

As I am working on a project that involves multiple developers, and we are using DVCS, each developer will be working on a feature branch assigned to them. That being said, the feature branches are branched out from the latest `develop` branch. In the `develop` branch, the db version in the `DatabaseHandler` is

> private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;

In my feature branch, I am required to make a new table. So I have to increase the version to 3, so I can include the following in `onUpgrade` to execute the `CREATE_APPLIANCE_TABLE` statement.

```
@Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        Log.d("Database onUpgrade", "Old is: " + oldVersion + ". New is: " + newVersion);
        switch(oldVersion) {
            case 1:
            db.execSQL(CREATE_USER);
        case 2:
            db.execSQL(CREATE_APPLIANCE_ACTIVITY); // for version 3
    }
}
```

My concern is, what if another developer needs to make a new table too, and he carries out the same process as me. Do he increase the version in his feature branch to 3? And if so, what should be our next step when either or both of us close our feature branch and merged it into `develop`? Since we both edited the same file, there may be chance of conflict. So in the `develop` branch, do the version stay at 3, or?

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand your questions. When you will merge your code files, you can put all your and his tables creating in one database version.
Like that:

```
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    Log.d("Database onUpgrade", "Old is: " + oldVersion + ". New is: " + newVersion);
    switch(oldVersion) {
        case **N**:
        db.execSQL(CREATE_YOUR_DATABASE); 
        db.execSQL(CREATE_HIS_DATABASE);
}
```

Comment: So does that means when both of our files are merged into `develop`, the database version will be 3? Initially in `develop` is 2. But on our individual feature, we increased to 3 because we need to add 1 new table for our feature.

Comment: If you both make it 3 - it will be 3. If you make it 2, but he make it 3 - it will be 3

Comment: Yup, we both made it 3 in order for `onUpgrade` to be executed. Alright, thanks for the help!

Comment: You're welcome! Just use merge tool =) Please, will not forget to choose my answer.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand, Whenever two developers work on the same file , at the time of merging branches last one to pull the changes will get the conflict in that file. So the last developer to pull changes can merge the changes manually after resolving all the conflicts.

In your case if version on develop is 2(Assuming version in market apk is 2) then next release version (market apk) for all branches will be 3, provided all features are included in that release.

Comment: yeap, last developer will see Code A (his) and Code B (of first developer), and he must to merge both to Code C.